# Does clang support __attribute__ ((alias))?

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

I couldn't find an official clang documentation for this.

The closest thing I found was this:

> C++11 alias templates
> Use __has_feature(cxx_alias_templates) or __has_extension(cxx_alias_templates) to determine if support for C++11’s alias declarations and alias templates is enabled.

from https://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html. I don't think it's related though.

I've tried using the `clang` command to compile and run a program with the alias attribute, and it seemed to work. But I'm not confident if this was a coincidence or not.

Could anyone shed more light on this? Is it ok to use this, or is there and alternative I should use?

Comment: I'm not an expert but how about this? https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#introduction

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I checked but it doesn't seem to explicitly state the attribute 'alias'? It does have noalias but I'm not sure if it's the same thing..

Comment: As I said I'm not an expert. It seams as Clang C++11 introduced function aliases in a native way. See https://www.fluentcpp.com/2017/10/27/function-aliases-cpp/ . So perhaps the  __attribute__(alias(""))  is an undocumented feature in Clang. Backward compatibility ?? "noalias" is unrelated IMHO

Comment: @PeterPaulKiefer I do appreciate your help! I don't have much background knowledge on this, so the sites you suggested are great. If Clang C++11 supports alias as a function, it does make sense it would also support it as an attribute...

Comment: Your welcome. But keep in mind that my experiences in this area are very limited ;-). I commented here, because noone else had done and I had some ideas. I hoped that someone with better understanding of the issue would correct me if I'm wrong. So, please take it as a guess and a starting point for further investigations. Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented in detail but it is listed to exist:

https://clang.llvm.org/docs/AttributeReference.html#alias

And whenever it's listed under the GNU column, it means that this attribute behaves the same as it does in GCC where it is documented:

https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.0.2/gcc/Function-Attributes.html#Function-Attributes